# Is there any texture amount limit in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I have made a complex scene with over 1 million faces/polygons.
I plan to use substance painter to texture the scene with 1k-4k textures (depending on the size). I need to know if there is any texture amount limit to Blender, for example, say I use 4k textures throughout a scene of 4 objects, but Blender can only support (allocate memory for) up to 3 objects with 4k texture. Is there any such limitation?

[image]

Comment: There is a Cuda limit for 256 textures: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities. I think you are fine, you are not likely to hit this limitation. It is easier to hit the VRAM limitation, all textures have to fit inside gpu memory if you want to use it for rendering..If that should be any issue you can render using Octane (and others..) - it can use system RAM for gpu rendering, such feature is not yet present in Cycles.

Comment: @Jerryno that link totally went over my head XD what do you mean by "There is a Cuda limit for 256 textures. As for my graphics card I use a MSI GTX 1050Ti OC Edition, how will that fair with the current task at hand considering I will be using around 10-15 4k textures?

Comment: Cycles uses Cuda for rendering on nvidia hardware. The limitation true to Cuda are therefore also limitations of Cycles. Cuda can load maximum of 256 textures inside it's kernel. One 4k texture will consume about 64MB of VRAM, so 15 * 64MB = 960MB. Your system might use about 600MB, cycles itself another 600MB, so together you will use approx 2.2GB of VRAM, which is less than 4GB that your card has. So you will be able to render that no problem with some headroom left.

Comment: @Jerryno wait, when you say 256 textures, do you mean 256 *unique* textures? Or does that include repeats too? I plan texture a grass and leaf elements and use them in an array modifier... So will that cross the limit of 256?

Comment: No, using the texture multiple times in a scene won't count towards the limit.

Comment: Only very old CUDA cards ("Fermi", which is the 4x0 and 5x0 series) have a number of textures limit in Cycles. On newer hardware, Cycles is using bindless textures, which in versions up to 2.78 allowed for a max of ~1024 textures, in 2.79 it can use millions of textures.